# Sorting Elements in a List Based on Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, heapq

I have a dictionary and I need the keys to be sorted according to their corresponding values. But the keys should not change the preset order when sorting is applied

The below example shows exactly what I am trying to do. The code returns the keys of first 3 highest values

**Code**

```
import heapq

val = {"a":3, "b":2, "c":4, "d":10, "e":6}

res = heapq.nlargest(3, val, key=val.get)
print(res)
```

**Current Output**

```
['d', 'e', 'c']
```

**Expected Output**

```
['c', 'd', 'e']
```

I tried this with heapq module but no use and usage of heapq module is not mandatory

Comment: But "d" does have a larger value than the others...

Comment: Yes. Among all the key value pairs, d, e, and c are the three keys with highest values. But when sorting among those 3, I need the first element in the original dict to come first

Comment: Any ideas how to proceed further? @KellyBundy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the heap is necessary here:

```
lookup_set = set(sorted(val.keys(), key=lambda x: val[x], reverse=True)[:3])
[i for i in val if i in lookup_set]
```

First creating a set of wanted keys, then filtering val.keys() to get the correct order.

yields:

```
['c', 'd', 'e']
```

To the people concerned of the ineffeciency of this:
O( n log n ) for sorting
O( n ) for making a set
O( n ) for linear filter of val keys afterwards.

Total O( n log n )

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
import heapq
val = {"a":3, "b":2, "c":4, "d":10, "e":6}

res = sorted(heapq.nlargest(3, val, key=val.get))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: Only working if the keys are in alphabetical order